# Understanding and extracting hashed images from ASP.NET and html

Tags: asp.net, html, hash, web-crawler

Okay this is a bit confusing to me, so I might not be able to explain this correctly.

I would like to update the quantity of an item listed on a supplier's website. I am writing a script that will connect to the site, search for a part, and then scrape the qty listing from the html in the site.

However, the quantity is not display in the return html, but instead is listed as a hash-coded link to an image, which contains the quantity. I think this is an attempt to keep the quantity updated.

Example:

After searching for the item, the website displays something like this:

```
MSRP:     Base:     Your Discount
$248.47   $185.01   32.00%
In Stock? 3
```

With the number "3" in green

I thought that it would be  easy then to grab the html from the site and pull the "In Stock? 3" span and use that.

However, this is (cleaned and pretty print) the html return from the site:

```
  <tr>
      <td>MSRP:</td> <td>Base:</td> <td>Your Discount</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>$248.47</td><td>$185.01</td><td>32.00 %<br /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>In Stock?</td>
     <td>
 <img id="ctl00_phCenterColumn_SearchResults_gvCatalog_ctl03_imgQtyDetailed"
  src="_controls/TextImage.aspx?Q7z=ecdb179e-0b2d-4baf-b74b-9c4d6afc3cb4">
 </td>
```

The image tag displays a picture of the quantity (an image only with the number 3).  It doesn't send the quantity as text.

I guess first,  What is the Q7z=* stuff?  Is it a hash of a picture for the quantity? I imagine it's there for keeping things up to date (especially quantity)

Second, is there a way to determine the quanitity from this information?

My only thoughts are to some how determine the value from the hash, or to use character recognition on the image... A little too much for just trying to determine the value.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Neal

Answer (score 0):

`Q7z=*` could be an identifer to the image since the source is an aspx page and not an image file directly.

That leaves you with decoding the image for information which is bit nasty. I would recommend finding a way to get text info (there must be a way since they are using it to append the query param `Q7z=*` stuff).

Comment: When you say "get text info (there must be a way..)"  could you clarify?